# Regular expression is correct, but doesn't work in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to drop a table cell from all of our XSL templates.
The code is the following:

```
<td width="100"><img src="/logos/code.png" border="0" width="100"/></td>
```

The code.png is different in every file. My regex is the following:

```
\<td.*\>\<img.*\/logos\/.*png.*\/\>\<\/td\>
```

I tested the expression on https://regex101.com/ and it matches to the above string, but when I try to find & replace with Notepad++, it gives me no match.
My xsl is all in one line, so line break cannot be the problem. Can someone help me, and give me a pattern that works in NP++?

Comment: You overescaped the pattern. Remove all ``\``. The `\<` matches the start of word position and `\>` matches the end of word position in NPP and `/` is not a special char.

Comment: also you use greedy statement

Comment: I just took Wiktor's suggestion in Notepad++ and it worked.  Also yes you might want to use `.*?` instead of `.*` to make the matches non-greedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not espace `<` and `>`.

Here is your regex : `<td.*?><img.*?\/logos\/.*?png.*?\/><\/td>`.
I also added `?` to our `.*` to ensure it won't act as greedy.

Comment: The `<img.*?\/logos\/.*?png.*?\/>` might overflow across many HTML tags.  `.` cannot be used to parse mark-up text.

Comment: yeah, you'r right. But shouldn't be ok in the case of an XLS? Without more informations i can't really improve the regex. For example, don't know if the `src` path will always start with /logos, is it possible to have an alt tag before the src, and so on.

Comment: This is the case where a verbose regex would work best. `<td\s+width="100"><img\s+src="/logos/[^"]*\.png"\s+border="0"\s+width="100"/></td>` or something like that.

Comment: I totally agree but, imo, there is not enought information on html tags format to produce such a regex.

Comment: Thanks, the pattern worked as expected, and the main question here was why doesn't my pattern work in NP++ and that was the escape issue.